# Allows music playback during recording video like snapchat flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

First I want to discuss the scenario happening in snapchat.

In snapchat when you start recording video and song is running in background; It allows continue that song while recording video and after you record that video you can also able to hear that song in background.

I am using the camera package, and every time I start recording a video, all external audio (i.e Spotify) is paused. I have to note that I have only been able to test this problem on an iOS physical device. Is there any way I could overcome this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Didi you come to any solution?

Comment: have u found any solution to this?